# What does "I can't say as I have high hopes where that is concerned" mean?

Tags: meaning

It's from the second episode of the first season of *Breaking Bad*. Here it is:

> Do you think he is capable of listening to reason?
>
> What kind of reason? You mean, "Dear Krazy-8, hey, listen...
>
> ...if I let you go, you promise not to come back and waste my entire
> family?
>
> No Colombian neckties?" That kind of reason?
>
> No, man, **I can't say as I have high fucking hopes where that's
> concerned**.

I am totally baffled by the grammar. First, what does the *as* mean there.

Comment: **High hopes** means **great expectations**. The preposition **as** here means **that**. "I can't say that there is much chance of it happening."

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comment! What about "where that is concerned"?

Comment: "Where that's concerned" means "regarding what was just said," presumably not much chance of that promise being kept. The dialog does not translate well to the written word, so I can't tell how many speakers there are, who is saying which sentence, or who is who (but I am not asking for more content).

Comment: "As" is used in place of "that". This is regional/casual/informal dialect. I can't say **that** I have high hopes (etc).